# How to save WebPack output files to another place automatically after my project is built

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ts-node

We have a SDK project witch is depended by another two projects.

When we want to build whole application, firstly, we need to build SDK project and upload it. Then we can build another two projects after run `npm install`.

This time I want to add a script for developer. When I run the script in SDK project it I can save the built output files to another projects `node_modules`.

Here is my code.

`package.json` file:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode=development",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

`webpack.config.js` file:

```js
let config = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test:/\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
  ...
}

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  if(argv.mode === 'development') {
    // We put all the projects in one repo
    config.output.path = path.resolve(__dirname,'../another-project/node_modules/sdk/dist/bundle')
  }
}
```

And at last we set `outDir` in `tsconfig.json`.

The problem is:

- How to change the output file path for typescript declaration files by WebPack arguments?
- How to save all the file to two places one time?

I figure out the last problem by using `webpack -env xxx && webpack -env xxx`. I just run script twice, maybe someone has better idear.

Now just one qusetion:

- **How to set the output file path for typescript declaration files dynamically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webpack.config.js` file:

```js
let config = {
  ...,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test:/\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          configFile: "tsconfig.server.json"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Then I can change `configFlie` in webpack module.

Answer (score 0):

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/

```
module.exports = {
...
  output: {
    filename: "lib.js"
  }
...
```

Configuring the out dir in typescript will not help you because webpack is the one responsible for compilation and will only use typescript for compilation after outputting the files itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help.


But here can only change the out JavaScript file folder path.

I need to change TypeScript declaration files out dir too.